# Why does this Phong shader work?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I recently wrote a Phong shader in GLSL as part of a school assignment. I started with tutorials, then played around with the code until I got it working. It works perfectly fine as far as I can tell, but there's one line in particular I wrote where I don't understand why it **does** work.

The vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;    // Vertex position
layout (location = 1) in vec3 Normal;      // Vertex normal

out vec3 Norm;
out vec3 Pos;
out vec3 LightDir;

uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;      // ModelView matrix without the translation component, and inverted
uniform mat4 MVP;               // ModelViewProjection Matrix
uniform mat4 ModelView;         // ModelView matrix
uniform vec3 light_pos;         // Position of the light

void main()
{
    Norm = normalize(NormalMatrix * Normal);
    Pos = Position;
    LightDir = NormalMatrix * (light_pos - Position);

    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(Position, 1.0);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 Norm;
in vec3 Pos;
in vec3 LightDir;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelView;

void main()
{
    vec3 normalDirCameraCoords = normalize(Norm);
    vec3 vertexPosLocalCoords = normalize(Pos);
    vec3 lightDirCameraCoords = normalize(LightDir);

    float dist = max(length(LightDir), 1.0);

    float intensity = max(dot(normalDirCameraCoords, lightDirCameraCoords), 0.0) / pow(dist, 1.001);

    vec3 h = normalize(lightDirCameraCoords - vertexPosLocalCoords);
    float intSpec = max(dot(h, normalDirCameraCoords), 0.0);
    vec4 spec = vec4(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0) * (pow(intSpec, 100) / pow(dist, 1.2));

    FragColor = max((intensity * vec4(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0)) + spec, vec4(0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 1.0));
}
```

So I'm doing the method where you calculate the half vector between the light vector and the camera vector, then dot it with the normal. That's all good. However, I do two things that are strange.

1. Normally, everything is done in eye coordinates. However, Position, which I pass from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, is in local coordinates.
2. This is the part that baffles me. On the line `vec3 h = normalize(lightDirCameraCoords - vertexPosLocalCoords);` I'm subtracting the light vector in camera coordinates with the vertex position in **local** coordinates. This seems utterly wrong.

In short, I understand what this code is supposed to be doing, and how the half vector method of phong shading works.

But why does this code work?

**EDIT:** The starter code we were provided is open source, so you can [download the completed project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46456893/A3_glut.zip) and look at it directly if you'd like. The project is for VS 2012 on Windows (you'll need to set up GLEW, GLM, and freeGLUT), and should work on GCC with no code changes (maybe a change or two to the makefile library paths).

Note that in the source files, "light_pos" is called "gem_pos", as our light source is the little gem you move around with WSADXC. Press M to get Phong with multiple lights.

Comment: are you absolutely certain it works *right*? It could just coincidentally look not completely broken :)

Comment: May be origin of object aligns with world origin

Comment: melak47: It does work, I got 100% on my assignment. It runs fine and makes my model look appropriately shiny no matter where I move the light  :D

Comment: Abhishek: Now that you mention it, the model is indeed at the world origin

Comment: So you actually recompute all your normals each time the camera moves? Anyway, it seems unlikely you're getting the *right* result, but if your object is smallish (comparable to unit radius), centered on the origin and reasonably convex you'll probably get a result that looks shiny, yes (your local vertex coordinate then approximates the surface normal). Your half-way vector will be on the wrong side due to the subtraction, so your highlights will be in the wrong place (though again, it will still look shiny :)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this works is happenstance, but it's interesting to see why it still works.

**Phong shading is three techniques in one**

With phong shading, we have three terms: *specular*, *diffuse*, and *ambient*; these three terms represent the three techniques used in phong shading.

None of these terms strictly require a vector space; you can make phong shading work in world, local, or camera spaces as long as you are consistant. Eye space is usually used for lighting, as it is easier to work with and the conversions are simple.

*But what if you are at origin?* Now you are multiplying by zero; it's easy to see that there's no difference between any of the vector spaces at origin. By coincidence, at origin, it doesn't matter what vector space you are in; it'll work.

```
vec3 h = normalize(lightDirCameraCoords - vertexPosLocalCoords);
```

Notice that it's basically subtracting 0; this is the only time local is used, and it's used in the one place that it can do the least damage. Since the object is at origin, all it's vertices should be at or very close to origin as well. At origin, the approximation is exact; all vector spaces converge. Very close to origin, it's very close to exact; even if we used exact reals, it'd be a very small divergence, but we don't use exact reals, we use floats, compounding the issue.

Basically, you got lucky; this wouldn't work if the object wasn't at origin. Try moving it and see!

Also, you aren't using [**Phong shading**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading); you are using [**Blinn-Phong shading**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model) (that's the name for the replacement of reflect() with a half vector, just for reference).

Comment: It seems unlikely that all his vertices are at the origin?

Comment: @heinrichj Everything except vertexPosLocalCoords is in terms of eye view; it's the only odd man out, and it's only used for a subtraction. Since the object is at origin, all the vertices should also be (or very close). This means that the accuracy is unusual high, despite the incorrect vector space being used.

Comment: Even if all its vertices are exactly at the origin, the resulting half-way vector is still completely off, unless the light direction happens to be the same as the eye direction. So I wouldn't call the accuracy high :)

Comment: @heinrichj No, the half-way vector is not "completely off"; it's remarkably close, because you are subtracting a very small number (or 0). Given all of this is approximations (or just straight up kludges) of the lighting equation, it's a little unfair to call it inaccurate; Phong shading itself is inaccurate.

Comment: The half-way vector is what the name suggests: half-way between the eye and light directions. As such, if you subtract zero from the light direction, you do not get the half-way vector unless the eye direction is identical.

Comment: Ooh, moving the model does indeed cause the shader to stop working properly. Followup question though: why doesn't changing the vertex shader to `Pos = NormalMatrix * Position` fix the problem? When I do this, everything still looks funky, and the specular highlights are fixed on the model (don't move when I move the camera). Or alternatively, what would be the fix to make my code work in all cases?

Comment: @Lewis: As I mentioned, the shader isn't "working properly" as is, though it might look acceptably "nice" :) Also, in a phong shading model the specular highlights *should* move along the surface if you move the camera, because they are brightest where the surface normal coincides with the half-way vector, which depends on both the eye vector and the light vector. Your computation of "h" is completely wrong; modifying the vertex position used there isn't going to fix it. Also, multiplying the vertex position with the normal transform doesn't make sense (in the best case missing translations).